# How can i convert this javascript function into java

Tags: java, javascript

let say i have fallowing javascript function-

```
function isDigit (c)
{ return ((c >= "0") && (c <= "9"))
}
function isAlphabet (c)
{
return ( (c >= "a" && c <= "z") || (c >= "A" && c <= "Z") )
}
```

How can i write same thing in java.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class methods.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char) and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)

Comment: @AndreyAdamovich : Links are for jdk 5 update them for jdk 6.

Comment: @Harry, methods didn't really change since that and I can't really edit my comments :)

Comment: @Andrey For tips on getting a link to the latest JavaDocs, see [point 2](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: Worth nothing that the Character equivalents handle all character sets. e.g. 208 characters are digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isDigit(char c) { 
  return ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'));
}

public boolean  isAlphabet(char c) {
  return ( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Respectively:

```
java.lang.Character.isLetter(c);
java.lang.Character.isDigit(c);
```

But if you want to make your own implementations:

```
boolean isAlpa(char c) {
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'; /* single characters are
            enclosed with single quotes */
}
```